# webdriver_manager opens google chrome instead of brave

Tags: python, webdriver, webdriver-manager

[webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) site has a code to start webdriver with brave, but instead of brave it opens it with google chrome. My selenium version 4.6.0 gave the following code for selenium 4 (I also tried the given codes for selenium 3) as it can be seen on the site, but the webdriver still opens with chrome

```
# selenium 4

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as BraveService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=BraveService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.BRAVE).install()))

driver.get("https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you just want to start a driver with Brave browser instead of chrome? Here is how I do that simplely, keep in mind I'm on Mac. You need the binaryPATH to the application.

```
add_block_ext = "Path to .crx extension"
driverPath = 'chromedriver'
binaryPath = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = binaryPath
options.add_extension(add_block_ext)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binaryPath, chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```